# Unable to find an entry point named uv_loop_size when launching Kestrel http server

Tags: dnx, dnvm, kestrel-http-server

I created a simple ASP.NET 5 web app using yeoman under Ubuntu:

- yo aspnet
- cd WebApplication
- dnu restore
- dnx web

And I am getting the following error:

```
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point named 'uv_loop_size' in DLL 'libuv'.
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Networking.Libuv.NativeMethods.uv_loop_size()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Networking.UvLoopHandle.Init(Libuv uv)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.KestrelThread.ThreadStart(Object parameter)
```

I made sure libuv-dev is installed : sudo apt get install libuv-dev

dnvm list: coreclr x64 1.0.0-rc1-final

My project.json is:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet5-WebApplication-2031e5cf-daec-4942-ab2d-94e0109e4d99",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "tooling": {
    "defaultNamespace": "WebApplication"
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.SQLite": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime":"1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions" : "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [
      "npm install",
      "bower install",
      "gulp clean",
      "gulp min"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recompiled libuv from source following these instructions and it solved the issue:

http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-linux.html

Also don't forget to call ldconfig once the libraries have been installed after sudo make install